# How to solve the valgrind problem I am getting in my code?

Tags: c, valgrind

Down below is my code and it is for a doubly Linkedlist, the problems I am getting are in this function and it is saying that:
Use of uninitialised value of size 8
  at 0x400C71: append_linked_list (linked_list.c:83)
and,
Invalid write of size 8
  at 0x400c71: append_linked_list (linked_list.c83)

```
Node *append_linked_list(LinkedList *list, void *data)
{   

    Node *tailnode;

    if (list == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: list is empty.");
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {  
        tailnode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        tailnode -> data = data;
        tailnode -> next = 0;
        tailnode -> prev = list -> tail;
        (list -> tail) -> next = tailnode;
        list -> tail = tailnode; 
    }

    return tailnode; 
}
```

Line 83 is

```
(list -> tail) -> next = tailnode;
```

Comment: Style note: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should not be written with spaces around them.  Use `list->tail->next` (your parentheses are also unnecessary) with no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

That means that

```
list -> tail
```

doesn't contain a valid pointer.

Comment: Yes but how shall I go to the tail and then go next, where tail and next are on different structs ?

Comment: `( list -> tail ) -> next` is perfectly fine that. (The parens aren't necessary.) But first, you need to make `list  -> tail` point to the tail.

Comment: Yeah, but even with or without the parens I get these problems

Comment: Right, because `list -> tail` doesn't contain a valid pointer. You need to make `list -> tail` point to the tail first.

Comment: IOW, @Tomiisme, you need to show the code that initializes the list.  In fact, you need to provide an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses;
MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
That would include a `main()` program (function) and would show how the `LinkedList` is set up, an so on.